# adding href using javascript append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Probably a rudimentary for some, but this is driving me crazy! I am not sure what I did wrong - I cannot/not allowed(?) to append a href - it is simply didn't get processed at all.

```
$('#lastViewed').append('<a href="/Path/To?_q="' + string + '>');
$('#lastViewed').append(.....some other stuffs.....);
$('#lastViewed').append('</a>');
```

I am trying to wrap the "other stuffs" with a 
Thanks!

**Edit**
The complete line:

```
$('#lastViewed').append('<div id="id_' + x + '<a href="/PVProduct/ProductDetail?_productID=' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pid_" + x)).productID);
```

Comment: What's `string`? Also, you're closing the `"` too early. `$('#lastViewed').append('<a href="/Path/To?_q=' + string + '">');` will probably work - can I close as typo? Also, cache your selectors.

Comment: `'<div id="id_' + x + '<a`: You don't have a closing `>` for the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect. You don't `append()` opening and closing tags like that. Instead, `append()` the whole tag. Or even better, create the `a` element and `append()` it:

```
$a = $('<a>').attr('href', yourHref).html(yourText);
$('#lastViewed').append($a);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct way of using the append keyword.  I ended up building a string and insert it in the <a> tag.  Thanks much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember, jQuery had `appendTo()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it

```
var link=document.createElement("a");
link.id="idName";
link.setAttribute("href", "your link");
document.appendChild(link);
```